# installing nodejs application goabally is not running

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a CLI application. I am using nodejs, I am just trying to run the file globally.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bin/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": {
    "hello": "./bin/index.js"
  }
}
```

also, I installed the application globally `npm i -g .`

but when i am running the application globally I am getting this error

[image]

---

The `bin/index.js`

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) present in `bin/index.js`, [the script gets run using `sh`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang) causing the error.
Add the Node shebang to run it with Node.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('Hello, World!');
```